# Piping to "xclip" doesn't survive bash script termination

Tags: linux, bash, xclip

I have an interactive `fzf` bash script that puts my choice into the `X` clipboard, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /path/to/file.txt | fzf | xclip -sel p -sel s -sel c

exit 0
```

The text file contains some lines:

```
one
two
three
four
five
```

If I launch the script from within a terminal emulator manually: `bash path/to/script.sh`, then `xclip` permanently stores piped content and it is available to paste even after closing the terminal emulator.

However, I want to bind it to a keyboard shortcut within my DE to use on demand, so I need to use it with a terminal emulator command, like: `mate-terminal -x bash /path/to/script.sh`. It opens fine, but as soon as it terminates after making my choice, the `xclip` content is lost and not available anymore to paste. If I delay the script's termination with `sleep 5`, then while the terminal is still open, pasting piped content works, but as soon as it terminates, it is lost.

I need a way for the `X` clipboard to keep the content even after the terminal emulator closes.

Comment: Because otherwise the script would launch in the background, without possibility of interaction from the user with `fzf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-loops 0` option (default). Make the X selection indefinitely available, until another process requests ownership of the X selection.

However, binding the program to a keyboard shortcut kills the xclip daemon after it returns. This behavior is not present when launching the program from a terminal. The `-verbose` option keeps the program running in the foreground, which causes the terminal to be kept around as well.

To keep the `xclip` daemon running, with no terminal window visible, an option is to use the `nohup` program. It runs a command which will have the init process as PPID (e.g. systemd).

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /path/to/file.txt | fzf | nohup xclip -loops 0 -sel p -sel s -sel c
```

Comment: It doesn't work, and actually `-loops` already assumes `0` if not specified, according to the man page.

Comment: @StanShank I revised the answer with a specific solution to the case of the hotkey.

Comment: Thank you! I have additionally prevented the creation of `nohup.out` by appending `>/dev/null 2>&1`.